# Sass bleeding edge version installed but 3.2.9 in use

Tags: rubygems, terminal, sass

I have successfully installed the bleeding edge of Sass but the 3.2.9 version is in use when I type `sass -v`. When I list gems I see the bleeding edge, however.

[image]
[image]

Comment: What happens when you run the commands in the *same* terminal?

Comment: Are you using RVM, rbenv and/or bundler? Also, try to do `which sass` to see where it is executed from.

Comment: With bundler (Gemfile): `bundle show sass`

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a clear as well

```
gem uninstall sass

compass clean
```

check if sass has gone: sass -v

If it has then reinstall it

```
gem install sass

gem update
```

then check the version again

```
sass-v or gem list
```

Current version is 3.3.12